# Value Semantics in Parallel Programming

Tags: math, prolog, semantics, logic-programming, ppl

What is the advantage of following value semantics while designing parallel programming?

Comment: Why are you not asking your teacher this?

Comment: Please explain me the topic seems very confusing to me.